# execute the following jquery code when a select menu changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, select-menu

I have some text fields that get shown/hidden by a select menu.  When this happens a script which is monitoring the values of the text fields for changes doesn't fire correctly.  For some reason it is not noticing the change.

## script:

```
var somethingChanged = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input, select').change(function() { 
        somethingChanged = true; 
        console.log($(this).attr('name')+ ' has changed'); 

$('input[class*=input]').focus(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('left')) {
    $(this).parent().addClass("lightOverlay");
    console.log($(this).attr('name')+ ' added lightOverlay'); 
    }
}).blur(function () {
    if (this.value == ''){
        $(this).parent().removeClass('lightOverlay')
        console.log($(this).attr('name')+ ' removed lightOverlay'); 
    }
})

$('input[class*=input]').focus(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('right')) {
    $(this).parent().addClass("lightOverlayRight");
    console.log($(this).attr('name')+ ' added lightOverlayRight'); 
    }
}).blur(function () {
    if (this.value == ''){
        $(this).parent().removeClass('lightOverlayRight')
    console.log($(this).attr('name')+ ' removed lightOverlayRight'); 
    }
})
})
});
```

How can I execute this code when the select menu changes?

here is the site in question with the full code:
http://2plygraphics.com/im-here/

you will see on the site that if you add values to 3 names and then set it to 7 names the names on the right don't apply the background image correctly until you click in them...I'd like to have the code check on the select menu change and update the background accordingly.

I'd like to change it to something like this (basically wrap the whole thing in a function that gets called when the select menu is clicked):

```
var somethingChanged = false;
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('select').click (function () {
    $('input, select').change(function() { 
        somethingChanged = true; 
        console.log($(this).attr('name')+ ' has changed'); 

$('input[class*=input]').focus(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('left')) {
    $(this).parent().addClass("lightOverlay");
    console.log($(this).attr('name')+ ' added lightOverlay'); 
    }
}).blur(function () {
    if (this.value == ''){
        $(this).parent().removeClass('lightOverlay')
        console.log($(this).attr('name')+ ' removed lightOverlay'); 
    }
})

$('input[class*=input]').focus(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('right')) {
    $(this).parent().addClass("lightOverlayRight");
    console.log($(this).attr('name')+ ' added lightOverlayRight'); 
    }
}).blur(function () {
    if (this.value == ''){
        $(this).parent().removeClass('lightOverlayRight')
    console.log($(this).attr('name')+ ' removed lightOverlayRight'); 
    }
})
})
    });
});
```

but that doesn't seem to work....Noob central over here!!! please help!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried keyup for textinput?

example

```
$('input[type=text]').keyup(function() {
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it only worked after the first click, not even keyup on the initial field entry.